# "I hope you write those letters thick." is correct?

Tags: adverbs, modifiers

I am not a native English speaker,
but to me, the sentence below sounds natural.

> "I hope you write those letters thick."

But I also definitely know that the following sentence is correct.

> "I hope you write those letters thickly."

Is the former also correct?

Comment: Could you say more about the meaning? The adjective thick (or the adverb thickly) are not usually applied to words or writing. Oh are you referring to penmanship or calligraphy? If so a different verb (draw) or a different noun (letters) might be more conventional.

Comment: could you give it more context? are you talking about stackexchange formatting? or is this a more general thing?

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone I am sorry for confusing you. I should have used **letters** instead of **word**.

Comment: @Sam Harrington Sorry for being stupid. I am not a native English speaker and I meant as I commented right above.

Comment: No it's not stupid I was just making sure everyone was on the sam page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your previous question, it's clear that the term you are looking for is **bold**.  Bold text is text that appears thicker than the text surrounding it.

As for this question, you probably want to use

> I hope you write that word in bold.

Bold is occasionally used as a verb, so

> I hope you bold that word.

could also be acceptable.

Comment: Also, we would not say *write that word **boldly*** if we meant *write it in bold*.

Comment: @GoDucks I would like to know if it could be alright grammatically. I wish to stick to "thick", and changed the object "that word" into "those letters". Why I am asking you this is to know about whether Object-Complement adjective can also be used with the verb "write".

Comment: I guess so, grammatically. I hope you serve that food hot. I hope you write those letters tall and straight. (The word 'thick' still seems weird here.)

Comment: @GoDucks Thank you for the helpful reply. I am so grateful to you.

Comment: @GoDucks Though some time has passed from the previous comment, can I ask you one more question? Is "I hope you write those letters bold." correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you must use a variation on *thick*, which sounds a little bizarre to a native speaker, use:

> I hope you write those letters thickly.

This is because *thick* is an adjective, however is being used here to modify the verb *write*, which is not grammatically correct. *Thickly* is an adverb, and therefore it is correct to use it to modify a verb.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Mr.Ivan. But, I wanted to regard "thick" as an object complement, not an adverb that modifies the verb "write".